# Safe way to `enable-local-variables`?

Tags: security, file-local-variables

I inherited my .emacs file from a friend about 18 years ago.  Buried in the middle is the following ominous comment warning about the security implications of the `enable-local-variables` feature:

```
;; Date: Wed, 7 Dec 1994 11:57:50 -0600
;; From: blob@syl.dl.nec.com (David Blob)
;; Subject: Self-extracting emacs elisp code
;;
;; With all this talk about self extracting mail "viruses", a friend
;; showed me that in emacs (which I use to read mail, along with vm)
;; has the ability to self-extract elisp code. This feature seems to
;; be turned on by default, and it not only applies to mail read with
;; emacs, but rather every file visited (when the feature is on, of
;; course).
;;
;; The way it works is by having a line which reads "Local Variables:"
;; followed by the lisp variables you would like to set...well, it may
;; seem petty, but you can execute programs, make connections and much
;; more through cleverly written elisp code contained within.
;;
;; It's simple to turn off, at any rate...
;;
;; (setq enable-local-variables  f) ;; turns off feature  (in emacs 19)
;; (setq enable-local-variables  1) ;; makes it ask first (in emacs 19)
;; (setq inhibit-local-variables t) ;; turns off feature  (in emacs 18)
;;
;; Anyhow, I think the risks here speak for themselves...
;;
(setq enable-local-variables '())
```

So I've never actually used the `local-variables` feature even though it seems like it could be pretty useful.  Is there a way to `enable-local-variables` that does something useful without exposing me to arbitrary code-injection attacks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

18 years ago, you were right to be worried. But time has marched on. Since Emacs 22, there is a decent built-in mechanism to whitelist safe local variables. The details are documented in the [Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html#File-Local-Variables) manual. The most important aspects are:

- Lisp authors can declare safe values for each variable. This is a whitelist: if the Lisp programmer hasn't done anything special, all values are considered unsafe.
- If `enable-local-variables` is set to `t` (the default), Emacs will automatically set safe values and prompt for confirmation if a file attempts to set an unsafe value. Once the user has approved a value for a given variable, this is automatically recorded and Emacs will not ask again about the same value for the same variable.
- If `enable-local-variables` is set to `:safe`, Emacs will automatically set safe values and ignore the others.

So you can keep the default setting if you don't mind being prompted, or use
`(setq enable-local-variables :safe)` to get the common benefits (indent style, timestamp format, etc.) with no risk and no user interface encroachment.

Comment: (For completeness / in case anyone is curious: Emacs 22 was released in 2007.)

Answer (score 10):

Emacs is pretty safe when it comes to local variables. It does not actually evaluate anything for file- or directory-local variables, it only parses Lisp syntax. Also, a variable has to be declared "safe" before it will be set by Emacs, and that declaration also includes a predicate. So a variable can say "a file may set this, but only if it is a string".

This means that you can safely enable local variables. You can actually just leave the default value of `t` – Emacs will ask you about whether it should set variables that it does not deem safe, and you can examine those first.

Make sure you do *not* set this variable to `:all`, and *do* look at the values of variables first before setting them if Emacs asks you. You can use `:safe` to only set variables that Emacs deems safe and ignore the rest, but you can miss out on some stuff this way.

Comment: There are also `eval` variables. See <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html> `enable-local-eval`, which can lead to evaluating any code.